# Difference between "à quelle heure" and "quand"?

Tags: choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps, questions

It is unclear to me exactly what the distinction is between these two for asking questions beginning with *when*. Is there a well-defined difference?

For example, what is the difference here?

> Quand est-ce que tu pars ?

---

> À quelle heure est-ce que tu pars ?

When should the one be used rather than the other, or does it vary based on context?

It was mentioned in an answer to a separate question earlier today that *quand* is more for asking about the date than the hour. Is that always true? Should *quand* never be used for asking about the time, in any context?

Comment: C'est une question de contexte, et ce serait pareil en anglais je suppose (*What time* vs *when*). Dans [ta question](http://bit.ly/2ck6m9s) tu veux une réponse avec un horaire et pas seulement, cette après-midi, demain, tout à l'heure....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that "quand" is used in a much broader sense. So if you are asked:

> Man: Alors, quand est-ce qu'on part ? {So, when / how soon do we leave?}

The answer will vary greatly:

> Woman: Maintenant. {right now}
>
> Woman: Seulement après avoir fait les devoirs. {after doing the homework}
>
> Woman: C'est pour le mois prochain. {sometime in the next month}

---

Whereas "à quelle heure" is focussed on a specific time period:

> Man: Alors, à quelle heure est-ce qu'on part ?
>
> Woman: Entre 12h et 15h.

Comment: As a french speaker, I can confirm this !